# Formula based on picklist

Tags: formula

I am trying to create a formula that will put a 1 in a hidden field if the value of a picklist is equal to a specific value.  I keep getting stuck here and I can't figure out what I am missing?

IF(ISPICKVAL( Examiner_Type__c ="Pending Examiner Status","1","",))

Answer (score 10):

Try

IF(ISPICKVAL( Examiner_Type__c , "Pending Examiner Status"),"1","")